# Efficient way to sum over distinct values and create percentage over sums in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, sum, distinct

Assuming Ι have a dataframe like this:

```
df
         Day       Group      Counts   
        Monday       0          7                 
        Monday       0          45           
        Monday       1          70           
        Tuesday      1          18          
        Tuesday      1          13          
        Tuesday      0          84
```

How can I create a new column named 'percentages' with the percentages given by group and day?

```
expected df
         Day       Group      Counts    Percentage 
        Monday       0          7           7/52
        Monday       0          45          7/45 
        Monday       1          70          70/70 
        Tuesday      1          18          18/31
        Tuesday      1          13          13/31
        Tuesday      0          84          84/84
```

I am doing something like:

```
groupby('day', 'group').agg((F.count('Counts') / F.sumDistinct('Counts'))
```

but I am getting an error.

Should I use the Window function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach should generally work. You just need to provide an alias for the aggregation and put the expression into parentheses.

```py
df_agg = df.groupby('day', 'group').agg((F.count('Counts') / F.sumDistinct('Counts')).alias('Percentage'))
df = df.join(df_agg, join=['day', 'group'], 'left')
```

Comment: yes but this will perform the aggregation whereas I want to keep the original rows intact and have the duplicates for the uncollapsed groups.

Comment: I see what you mean. To get the desired result I added the necessary `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Window function, to count the elements per day and group, and then make the division:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
window = Window.partitionBy('Day','Group')
df = df\
    .withColumn('count_per_window', sum('Counts').over(window))\
    .withColumn('Percentage', col('Counts')/col('count_per_window'))\
    .drop('count_per_window')
```